# How can I make these marble textures?

Tags: cycles-render-engine, texturing

So I play a game called Astroneer. There are marbles in the game that I would really like to make.
Here are some images

[image]

[image]

The white parts are emission and the constellation texture has an image that I already can use.
Is there a way I can make these? I would like a detailed tutorial as I am not the best at Blender. This is in Cycles.

Thank You! :)

Answer (score 2):

And I can answer how to make the second material, pretty much.  Assuming that “the constellation texture has an image that I already can use” means you want to use that image texture, this uses some Math nodes as the Factor for a Mix Shader masking between that texture (using a placeholder ColorGrid in this example) and an Emission node:

[image]

This requires a Default Cube's UV map with the cube made spherical (Subdivision & Cast modifiers) to get the spots where they are, so it's not very flexible:

[image]

Got the idea to use Ping-Pong math nodes for this from this youtube vid:

https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=DThWrWYJMNg

And here's the blend file:

[image]

Answer (score 1):

I can at least answer how to make the **first** material. You'd have to first use a radial gradient with modified coordinates to give it a twist. Then use a musgrave texture to add the smudges and plug it into the Factor of a Shader Mix node between an emission and a glossy (or any other shader)

[image: The Nodetree]

[image: The material result]

Copy the nodetree and tweak settings to taste.